# What’s wrong here?

Tags: bug, reputation

For some reason our reputation league is [having some error](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/716/alltime/langdev/2023-05-16/114#114). What happened was it directed us to the “It’s not your fault. It’s our fault” error page. What happening and how can this be taken care of?

Comment: Nope it works on community building just fine @Bbrk24

Comment: Could a mod add status completed as it’s working now

Comment: Fair enough I have edited @RayButterworth

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not reproducible.

Comment: Its just fiex, thats all @pppery

Comment: Whats off topic about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, this has been fixed and is now [working properly](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/716/alltime/langdev/2023-05-16/114#114). No idea what happened though. Possibly related to the domain name change.